# Premium for unit payment given Life expectancy

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Given that $l_{70}=1000$, $l_{71}=960$, $l_{72}=912$, and the interest rates are at a constant $10%$, calculate $A_{70}(1_2)$.

---

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{Age} & l_x & d_x  \\
\hline
70 & 1000 & 0  \\
71 & 960 & 40 \\
72 & 912 & 88
\end{array}
$$

$A_x(b)=\sum^{w-x-1}_{k=0} b_k. v(k+1). \frac{d_{x+k}}{l_x}$

$=[(1.10)^{-1}. \frac{40}{1000}]+[(1.10)^{-2}. \frac{88}{1000}]=0.109$

But the answer is $0.0760$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are double counting $48$ people! Your term $d_2=88$ contains those who died in the first year and those that died in the second year. The correct calculation is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{1.1}\cdot\frac{40}{1000}+\frac{1}{1.1^2}\cdot\frac{48}{1000}=0.0760
\end{equation*}